# Retrieve checkbox label text using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript function to check all of the checkboxes in a checkbox list:

```
function processCheckbox (item) {
    $("input[name='" + item + "']").each( function () {
        if($(this).prop('id') === 'OPTIONS_2') {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    
    });
}
```

I need to leave one specific checkbox unchecked. the checkbox ID is `OPTIONS_2` and the above function worked fine at first but problems started occurring due to checkbox list being dynamic and so another option gotten switched to the position of `OPTIONS_2`.

I tried using `$(this).val()` in place of `$(this).prop('id')` but that would not work as the ID comes from the database and changes from environment to environment.

The only option is to use the label text but I am not sure how to get it using javascript.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="apex-item-option">
    <input type="checkbox" id="OPTIONS_2" name="OPTIONS" value="123">
    <label class="u-checkbox" for="OPTIONS_2">TEST</label>
</div>
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: **$(this).next().text()** this will get you the label text.

Answer (score 1):

$(this).next().text() === "TEST" worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.textContent` method to retrieve the label of the checkbox once you reach to label tag with the help of function `nextSibling`.

`$(this).nextSibling.textContent`

So let's take your example:

`$('#OPTIONS_2').nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent`

Comment: $(this).nextSibling comes up `undefined`

Comment: $(this).next().text() worked instead